# Action "foo/foobar" does not exist error in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I am saving pictures under my web folder in the folder:

web/media/photo

In the template that displays the photo, I have the following snippet:

```
<?php echo link_to(image_tag('media/photo/filename.jpg', '@some_url); ?>
```

When I display the view, although the photo is displayed correctly and the link works, I get the following error in my php_errors.log file:

> Action "media/photo" does not exist.

Why is symfony trying to parse the path to the image as a url?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you changed your .htaccess at all? When a file exists, the request should not make it to Symfony.

Answer (score 2):

Add a leading slash to the image path:

```
<?php echo link_to(image_tag('/media/photo/filename.jpg', '@some_url); ?>
```

This will prevent Apache from redirecting to the `media/photo` action in symfony that is matched the `mod_rewrite` rules in `.htaccess`.

Comment: `<?php echo link_to(image_tag('/media/photo/filename.jpg', '@some_url); ?>` is also missing some syntax - it should be `<?php echo link_to(image_tag('/media/photo/filename.jpg'), '@some_url'); ?>` but PHP should have thrown a parse error if you'd made that mistake in your code.